# Routing Get and Post to Different URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

**My Current Route**

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Start",
                url: "Home",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "GetStarted", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
        This route redirect to the URL /Home/
```

**ActionResult**

```
  [ActionName("GetStarted")]
        public ActionResult getStart(){
}
```

I need to create another route based on another action result like below which is HttpPost.

```
        [HttpPost]
        [EnsureHttpAttribute]
        [ActionName("GetStarted")]
        public ActionResult getStart(string ddl_week, string ddl_day){
    }
```

Url i want to redirect is **/Home/Program**. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your route to:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Start",
                url: "Home/{action}",
                defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "GetStarted", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
                );
```

If you actually want to post to a different URL, you have to specify that in your form which I assume is in your GetStarted View.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Program", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null }))
```

In your controller, change:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnsureHttpAttribute]
    [ActionName("GetStarted")]
    public ActionResult getStart(string ddl_week, string ddl_day){
    }
```

to

```
    [HttpPost]
    [EnsureHttpAttribute]
    [ActionName("Program")]
    public ActionResult Program(string ddl_week, string ddl_day){

    }
```

Comment: Noo.. I don't want to create a new action. Whenever i am calling this HttpPost action my url must be  /Home/Program. So I need to create another route. How can i create this?

Comment: Without creating a new actionresult how can i do this?

Comment: You have to have an Actionresult for Program. see above. Get rid of the httpost version of GetStarted because it's not needed. You need to have your html form point to the Program ActionResult.

Comment: I don't want to modify my 'Start' route. I need to create another route for the GetStart post action and the url should be /Home/Program when this action call.

Comment: the first route is working fine..I need a new route when the Post action call.

Comment: I need to change only the url .Change 'GetStarted' to 'Program' when Home/GetStarted action call. The first route is for GetStarted with HttpGet. I think now you can understand my requirement.